# Bring the Canvas to Front instead of the image

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

Hello i'm doing a simple program that loads a picture and adds a rectangle to the canvas.

i have this xaml code

```
<Grid>
            <Image x:Name="img"  Source="{Binding ImagePath, Source={x:Static vm:DrawingVM.instance}, Converter={StaticResource nullImageConverter}}" Stretch="None">
            </Image>

            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListRectangle, Source={x:Static vm:DrawingVM.instance}}" >
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Canvas  x:Name="cnvas" Width="{Binding ElementName=img, Path=ActualWidth}" 
                        Height="{Binding ElementName=img,Path=ActualHeight}"
                        LayoutTransform="{Binding ElementName=img, Path=LayoutTransform}">
                            <!--MouseDown="cnvas_MouseDown" MouseLeftButtonDown="cnvas_MouseLeftButtonDown"-->
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>

                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
                                    <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="MouseDownDrawing"  TargetObject="{Binding Source={x:Static vm:ResizerVM.instance}}"  />
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseMove">
                                    <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="MouseMoveDrawing"  TargetObject="{Binding Source={x:Static vm:ResizerVM.instance}}"  />
                                </i:EventTrigger>

                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" >
                                    <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="OnLeftButtonClicked"  TargetObject="{Binding Source={x:Static vm:ResizerVM.instance}}"  />
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown" >
                                    <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="MouseLeftButtonDownClicked"  TargetObject="{Binding Source={x:Static vm:ResizerVM.instance}}"  />
                                </i:EventTrigger>

                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" >
                                    <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="DragFinishedMouseHandler"  TargetObject="{Binding Source={x:Static vm:ResizerVM.instance}}"  />
                                </i:EventTrigger>


                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>


                        </Canvas>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}" Stroke="Blue"  Fill="Transparent" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>
```

What i'm trying to do is to draw a rectangle in the canvas but mouse. but it doesn't execute the event because the Image is UPPER. **how can i set the position of the IMAGE so that the CANVAS is UPPER?** so i can execute the event like drawing a rectangle using mouse

Answer (score 0):

If an item appears as a later child of a grid, it should be on top of previous elements and therefore should be getting input. However, if there is another item stealing input, you can set `IsHitTestVisible="False"` on the item and it should no longer be clickable.

If the Image doesn't turn out the be the element that's causing the problem, you might want to check other elements. To check is that another element is not consuming the input, try putting event handlers on other elements and see whether or not they trigger.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve the required outcome by making parent as Canvas instead of Grid and then set ZIndex property to controls inside Canvas , The Control which has highest ZIndex Will appear at front and then you can perform your required operation on it.

```
        <Canvas>
            <Image x:Name="img"  Source="{Binding ImagePath, Source={x:Static vm:DrawingVM.instance}, Converter={StaticResource nullImageConverter}}" Stretch="None" Panel.ZIndex="0">
            </Image>

            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListRectangle, Source={x:Static vm:DrawingVM.instance}}" Panel.ZIndex="1">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Canvas  x:Name="cnvas" Width="{Binding ElementName=img, Path=ActualWidth}" 
                        Height="{Binding ElementName=img,Path=ActualHeight}"
                        LayoutTransform="{Binding ElementName=img, Path=LayoutTransform}">
                            <!--MouseDown="cnvas_MouseDown" MouseLeftButtonDown="cnvas_MouseLeftButtonDown"-->
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>

                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
                                    <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="MouseDownDrawing"  TargetObject="{Binding Source={x:Static vm:ResizerVM.instance}}"  />
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseMove">
                                    <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="MouseMoveDrawing"  TargetObject="{Binding Source={x:Static vm:ResizerVM.instance}}"  />
                                </i:EventTrigger>

                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" >
                                    <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="OnLeftButtonClicked"  TargetObject="{Binding Source={x:Static vm:ResizerVM.instance}}"  />
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown" >
                                    <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="MouseLeftButtonDownClicked"  TargetObject="{Binding Source={x:Static vm:ResizerVM.instance}}"  />
                                </i:EventTrigger>

                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" >
                                    <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="DragFinishedMouseHandler"  TargetObject="{Binding Source={x:Static vm:ResizerVM.instance}}"  />
                                </i:EventTrigger>


                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>


                        </Canvas>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}" Stroke="Blue"  Fill="Transparent" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Canvas>
```